# Can we ever have $\Gamma \models \perp$

Tags: logic

Can we ever have $\Gamma \models \perp$? I think since as long as $\Gamma$ has a model, $\Gamma \models \perp$ can never be correct. So it is correct when $\Gamma$ has no model. Is my understanding right?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's exactly right: "$\Gamma\models\perp$" is equivalent to "$\Gamma$ has no model" (or "$\Gamma$ is unsatisfiable").